# How to make handlebars-loader used in conjunction with handlebars-helpers

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

how the [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader) to work with [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers)?

webpack.configs:

```
  { // handlebars-loader
    test: /\.handlebars$/,
    loader: "handlebars-loader?helperDirs[]=" + __dirname + "/helpers"
  }
```

but, how to import handlebars-helpers  and use handlebars-helpers

thanks!